# Large files over socket c Sharp

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, byte

I've read around and i'm hearing mixed things about this. Do you have to split a file into chunks to send it over a stream? or does the OS do that for you?

I have a byte array of about 320,000 values, which i need to get across a network. I can get the first several thousand over but anything after that, it's just set to 0.

I'm using the NetworkStream class, creating a TcpListener / TcpClient, getting the stream from the listener once connected and writing the array to the stream then flushing. Without Success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about how your message is broken into chunks, that's the point of using networking libraries - the transport is handled for you. Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 2):

When using TCP sockets, sending 1024 bytes may or may not be split into chunks by the OS. This behavior at our level should be considered undefined and the receiver should be able to handle a situation like that. What most protocols do is specify a certain (known) message size that contains information such as file size, what range of data it should read, etc. Each message the server constructs will have this header. You as the programmer can specify your chunk sizes, and each chunk must be reconstructed at the receiver level.

Here's a walkthrough:

1. Server sends a command to the client with information about the file, such as total size, file name, etc.
2. Client knows how big the command is based on a pre-programmed agreement of header size. If the command is 512 bytes, then the client will keep receiving data until it has filled a 512 byte buffer. Behind the scenes, the operating system could have picked that data up in multiple chunks, but that shouldn't be a worry for you. After all, you only care about reading exactly 512 bytes.
3. Server begins sending more commands, streaming a file to the client chunk by chunk (512 bytes at a time).
4. The client receives these chunks and constructs the file over the course of the connection.
5. Since the client knows how big the file is, it no longer reads on that socket.
6. The server terminates the connection.

That example is pretty basic, but it's a good groundwork on how communication works.